# Slow query takes up entire HDD space resulting in a "1030 Got error 28 from storage engine"

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb, mysql-error-1030

Fairly new to MySQL.

Slow query takes up the entire HDD space ending up with 1030 error code.

```
INSERT INTO schema.Table C
SELECT a.`Date`, a.Store, a.SKU, 
       floor((a.QTY / ((b.CASEQTY * b.CASEPERLAYER) * b.LAYERPERPALLET))) AS Pallets,
       floor(((a.QTY / ((b.CASEPERLAYER * b.LAYERPERPALLET) * b.CASEQTY)) /.CASEQTY)) AS Cases,
       (a.QTY * b.CASEQTY) AS Pieces
FROM
    (schema.table1 AS a
    INNER JOIN schema.table2 AS b)
    WHERE a.Description = 'BLAH';
```

**Problem:**

When I run the above query I get the results I need in 0.01 sec with a limit of 100 rows. However, When I try to insert the query into a prepared table it fails.

The above query will basically run for hours until the HDD is full. Table A contains millions of records and table B only a few thousand. Storage engine is InnoDB. I've run a similar query for 3hrs and have had it succeed. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner join statement contains no join criteria.  This will result in something (bad) called a "cartesian product".  So, if table A has a million records and table b contains a thousand, then a cartesian product will match each row in table A to EVERY row in the other table.  This should give you (at least) a billion records.

To fix this, you need to define/constrain the relationship between the two tables by using an "ON" clause for your join or it could go in the WHERE clause.

Comment: I totally forgot the ON clause! Thanks for pointing that out! I have spent 3 days trying to figure why this is happening thinking it had something to do with the InnoDB engine.

Answer (score 2):

That's something special in MySQL. In spite of calling it **INNER JOIN**, you can do a **CROSS JOIN** by leaving out the ON clause which is exactly what you are doing. (Another dbms would raise a syntax error.)

So by not specifying the ON clause to match records from table1 and table2 you match *every* record in table1 with *every* record in table2. These can be many :-)